# Adding my own package into Murano package repository in FIWARE

Tags: fiware, fiware-murano

I am trying to use Murano as my application deployment component, I was reading the information that I have from OpenStack but I do not know how can I add my own package to Murano package repository in FIWARE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use murano CLI to upload your package into murano catalogue. You can find some information in http://murano.readthedocs.org/en/latest/articles/client.html#importing-packages-in-murano. To use it, you just need to export your FIWARE Lab credentials and use murano package-import

```
export OS_USERNAME=(your_FIWARE_LAB_username)
export OS_TENANT_NAME=(your_FIWARE_LAB_tenant)
export OS_PASSWORD=(your_FIWARE_LAB_password)
export OS_AUTH_URL=http://cloud.lab.fiware.org:4731/v2.0
murano package-import /path/to/package.zip
```

Your package (package.zip) should have a concrete structure. You can find some information about how to create murano packages in http://murano.readthedocs.org/en/latest/articles/app_pkg.html#app-pkg.